# Is it possible to override a single textfield in Django admin?

Tags: python, django

I was looking to override only a single TextField in the Django admin but not have it influence the other textfield, which I would like to be the default. Here is what I have so far.

```
formfields_overrides={
    models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows':1, 'cols':40})}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [specify a form to be used](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) on the add/change pages. By default this is a plain old `ModelForm`.

Say your model is called `MyModel`, and you want to change the widget for `field1` but not for `field2`:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = MyModel
         widgets = {
             'field1': Textarea(attrs={'rows':1, 'cols':40}),
         }

...
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
```